# Mapping cone of a composition with a homotopy equivalence

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon B \to C$ be chain maps, and suppose that $g$ is a homotopy equivalence. I thought that the mapping cone $\mathrm{Cone}(f)$ of $f$ is homotopy equivalent to the cone $\mathrm{Cone}(gf)$ of the composition, however, I could not prove it.

**Question:** Is this a true statement? If so, how could we show it? If not, how could I think it is obviously false? (I thought it is *obviously* true at first glance.)

Just in case, let me note my first try here. Fix a homotopy inverse $g'\colon C \to B$ of $g$ and a homotopy $h\colon g'g \Rightarrow 1$.

- $g$ induces a map $G\colon \mathrm{Cone}(f) \to \mathrm{Cone}(gf)$,
- $g'$ induces a map $G'\colon \mathrm{Cone}(gf) \to \mathrm{Cone}(g'gf)$,
- $hf$ induces an isomorphism $H\colon \mathrm{Cone}(g'gf) \to \mathrm{Cone}(f)$.

Therefore it is enough to show that $HG'G \simeq 1$ and $GHG' \simeq 1$. The former equivalence is easy to see, but the latter seems false for me. In the first place, I am not using any information of the homotopy equivalence $gg' \simeq 1$, at all. Something seems wrong.

(The above question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378225).)

Answer (score 2):

After all, the claim was true. The induced map $G\colon \mathrm{Cone}(f) \to \mathrm{Cone}(gf)$ is homotopic to the map
\begin{equation}
G_0 =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
(h'g-gh)ft & g\\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $h'\colon gg' \Rightarrow 1$ is a homotopy and $t\colon A[1] \to A$ is the degree shift map. It is easy to see $GHG' \simeq G_0HG' \simeq 1$.